# Is there a way to change only SOME text in a specific column (and not the entire column) to be bold or italic in a table?

Tags: formatting, multicolumn, italic

Consider the following table. Some of the text in the second column is italic and also the text is broken in order to fit the column width.

[image]

[image]

I used the following tex code but it generates a table that is not centered and outside the page border on the right (see figure 2).

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{llll}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{S\#}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Required Input}}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Output}} \\ \cline{2-3}
                         & \textbf{1-level}   & \textbf{2-level} &   \\    \hline
 E-call (EC)                  & Vehicle information, e.g., type and       id,    vehicle location,\\ \textit{freight information, e.g., type and amount.}      &     Any output here. \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem with this code. Btw, don't use `\it` which is deprecated, use `\itshape` instead.

Comment: @Mico I edited the question so as to make my question clear. Can you suggest anything helpful please?

Comment: @Shoaib - I see nothing fundamentally different, as far as rendering material in italics is concerned, between the first and current versions of your posting. Please post the LaTeX code that gives rise to the screenshot you've posted -- maybe there's something in your code that's interfering with `\textit`.

Comment: So, what is the (new) question?

Comment: @Mico I uploaded the code and the screenshot of the generated table now. As i said earlier, your suggestion works well when there is only one-two columns in a table. But in my case I have 4 columns and i have to wrap the text in each column to shrink the table so it can fit in to the page width. For that reason one solution is to use tabular inside a tabular and then use line breaks but the problem with that kind of approach is that i cannot make the text italic or bold.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you've tried, but the following should work to generate *italic* text.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}  
%% Be sure to select the desired width of the "tabularx" environment
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}[c]{@{}X@{}}
    Vehicle information, e.g., type and id, vehicle  location,
    \textit{freight information, e.g., type and amount.}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

To generate **bold** text, use `\textbf{...}`; to generate ***bold italic*** text, use `\textbf{\textit{...}}`.

Comment: the code you presented works ok but I am using a multi-column table. I am new here and cannot edit my question so I will try to post a new question with the table picture that i want. For some reason, the code above does not work when used in a muti-column table. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Shoaib - I will freely admit to being a terrible, dreadful, no good whatsoever mind-reader. If something isn't mentioned, I will invariably fail badly at guessing what it may be that wasn't mentioned. Please do post a new query that states fully what you need to achieve.